# Sed or Awk filtering on floating point numbers

Tags: command-line, sed, awk, grep

I have a line in a file that reads:

```
"p" : "1.87","cs" : "chb","c" : "0.00","cp" : "0.00","b" : "2.25"
```

What I would like it to read is:

```
"p" : 1.87,"cs" : "chb","c" : 0.00,"cp" : 0.00,"b" : 2.25
```

and just get rid of the double quotes around the floating point numbers

Comment: Please show us what you have tried so far.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do it in **sed** with this command.

```
sed -i.bak -r 's/"([0-9]+\.[0-9]+)"/\1/g' data.txt
```

Comment: Tried that, it just prints the whole line out and no " are removed.

Answer (score 0):

Using `gnu awk` (default `awk` in ubuntu) you can do this:

```
awk '{print gensub(/"([0-9]+\.[0-9]+)"/,"\\1","g")}' file
"p" : 1.87,"cs" : "chb","c" : 0.00,"cp" : 0.00,"b" : 2.25
```